# Attaching files to allure report using cucumber failing with a 'Closed Stream' error

Tags: ruby, cucumber, allure

Allure report generation has started failing for me for the past couple of weeks. I get a 'Closed Stream' error on the following line in my hooks.rb file which I use to take screenshot on scenario failure. Here are a few relevant lines from the ruby file-

```
def take_screenshot(scenario_name)
    screenshots_path= 'artifacts/screenshots/'
    unless File.directory?(screenshots_path)
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(screenshots_path)
    end
    puts "scenario name is  #{scenario_name}"
    page.driver.browser.save_screenshot "#{screenshots_path}/#{scenario_name}.png"
end
*******
    if scenario.failed?
        path = take_screenshot(scenario.name)
        puts "path to attach #{path}"
        AllureCucumber::DSL.attach_file("#{scenario.name}.png -FAILURE Screenshot", path) if ENV['ALLURE']=='true'
    end
```

The allure report generation is failing because of the last line

```
AllureCucumber::DSL.attach_file("#{scenario.name}.png -FAILURE Screenshot", path) if ENV['ALLURE']=='true'
```

which attaches the screenshot file to the report saying "IOError Closed Stream". What is going wrong here?

Comment: I would check a few things. Make sure the server is not reaching it's performance capacity. Make sure the files aren't being blocked by the server because they're too large. And make sure the file is able to be accessed at the moment you read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did more investigation and found out that the line-

```
AllureCucumber::DSL.attach_file("#{scenario.name}.png -FAILURE Screenshot", path) if ENV['ALLURE']=='true'
```

is actually referring to the attach_file method in capybara gem -

[https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb][1]

and failing.

I used pry and debugged to get this-

> [1] pry(#)> AllureCucumber::DSL.attach_file("#{scenario.name} -FAILURE
>   Screenshot", path) #if ENV['ALLURE']=='true' IOError: closed stream
>   from
>   /Users/rv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:154:in
>   each' [2] pry(#)> attach_file("#{scenario.name} -FAILURE
>   Screenshot", path) #if ENV['ALLURE']=='true' IOError: closed stream
>   from
>   /Users/rv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:154:ineach'

Finally figured out that this was happening as one of the step definition files had a library include for capybara which was overriding the **attach_file** method.